# How to use HttpClient (or whatever) into a Database SQL Server project in .NET to call a external service?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlclr

What I'm trying to do simply is execute a CLR Stored Procedure from SQL Server 18 which is aiming to a database project created in Visual Studio 2019, sending a parameter (an URL), to try to be executed into VS, but when the WebRequest object receives my parameters, seems the WebRequest doesn't do nothing, and what I need is to call that URL from another project.

I have tried with a library class in another project, putting there a HttpClient object and it works succesfully. Another thing I've tried is creating a library class into the datbase project and try to interconnect them, to try to call the method I know works (with HttpClient object) but neither let me references it.

- SQL SERVER statements:

```
ALTER DATABASE SellerCenter SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
------------------------------------------------
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO
    RECONFIGURE
GO
--------------------------------
CREATE ASSEMBLY [CLR_GetFeed]
    FROM 'D:\CLR_SPs\SQL_CLRs.dll'
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS
GO
-----------------------------
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetFeed
    @url nvarchar(2000)
AS
    EXTERNAL NAME CLR_GetFeed.StoredProcedures.CLR_GetFeed
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------
EXECUTE sp_GetFeed @url = 'https://localhost:44325/api/order'
```

.NET code:

```
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void CLR_GetFeed (SqlString url)
    {
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(string.Format($"[{url.ToString()}]"));
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
    }
}
```

Is here when I try to connect the above method with this lower one, but has been impossible to try to make see the CLR_GetFeed (above) with the GetFeedRedirect(below):

```
public class RedirectLinks
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetFeedRedirect()
        {
            string responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:44325/api/order");

            return responseString;
        }
    }
```

When I execute the SP (sp_GetFeed) with the parameter (URL), it run succesfully and shows me the URL as a message in the Messages part in SQL Server, but never executes the URL, I mean, I need to call an external service that aims to an API.

Comment: What is the actual error/issue? Also, I don't see where you call into GetFeedredirect.

Comment: What I really need is to Call a REST API Service from SQL Server using C# SQL CLR, but I'm getting the next error message:
```Error de solicitud de permiso de tipo 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.```

Comment: When, where are you getting this error?